# Populating table based on dynamic created headers AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

First to introduce to my table structure:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Pair</th>
                      <th id="{{odds.id}}" ng-repeat="odds in list">{{odds.odd.name}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="match in matches ">
                        <td>{{match.sd | parseMomentDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{match.h}}-{{match.a}}</td>
                        <td>{{match.odds.drawNoBet.value}}<span ng-if="!match.drawNoBet.value">--</span></td>                   
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I am listing odd names, and therefore setting up id attr for the  element.

[image]

So my problem is how to populate the rest of the table, the table data based on the Id from the table head, every table head to have rows and columns populated based on that id?

I have the next structure of receiving the data:

```
   "id": 4413011,
            "sd": "2017-04-27T23:30:00.000+0400",
            "h": "Athletic Bilbao",
            "a": "Betis Sevilla",
            "odds": {
                "bothToScore": [
                    {
                        "name": "no",
                        "value": 1.85,
                        "id": 552240303
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "yes",
                        "value": 1.95,
                        "id": 552240338
                    }
                ],
                "doubleChance": [
                    {
                        "name": "12",
                        "value": 1.22,
                        "id": 552240012
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "x2",
                        "value": 2.98,
                        "id": 552240003
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "1x",
                        "value": 1.11,
                        "id": 552240079
                    }
                ],
                "drawNoBet": [
                    {
                        "name": "1",
                        "value": 1.15,
                        "id": 552240007
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "2",
                        "value": 6.15,
                        "id": 552240267
                    }
                ],
                "totalGoals": [
                    {
                        "name": "under",
                        "value": 2.15,
                        "id": 552235662
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "over",
                        "value": 1.7,
                        "id": 552235663
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

So for example in the odds object there is a list "bothToScore", therefore "bothToScore" is the id for the table head, and based on that id need to populate the rest of the columns, meaning ;Yes' or 'No'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

At this case `id` mapping is not needed - just ensure same order of `<th>`s and `<tr>`s:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.matches = [{
      "id": 4413011,
      "sd": "2017-04-27T23:30:00.000+0400",
      "h": "Athletic Bilbao",
      "a": "Betis Sevilla",
      "odds": {
        "bothToScore": [{
          "name": "no",
          "value": 1.85,
          "id": 552240303
        },
        {
          "name": "yes",
          "value": 1.95,
          "id": 552240338
        }],
        "doubleChance": [{
          "name": "12",
          "value": 1.22,
          "id": 552240012
        },
        {
          "name": "x2",
          "value": 2.98,
          "id": 552240003
        },
        {
          "name": "1x",
          "value": 1.11,
          "id": 552240079
        }],
        "drawNoBet": [{
          "name": "1",
          "value": 1.15,
          "id": 552240007
        },
        {
          "name": "2",
          "value": 6.15,
          "id": 552240267
        }],
        "totalGoals": [{
          "name": "under",
          "value": 2.15,
          "id": 552235662
        },
        {
          "name": "over",
          "value": 1.7,
          "id": 552235663
        }]
      }
    }];
    $scope.matches.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.matches[0])));
}]);
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Pair</th>
        <th ng-repeat-start='(key, value) in matches[0].odds' hidden></th>
        <th ng-repeat-end ng-repeat='item in value'>{{item.name}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='match in matches'>
        <td>{{match.sd | date}}</td>
        <td>{{match.h}} - {{match.a}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat-start='(key, value) in match.odds' hidden></td>
        <td ng-repeat-end ng-repeat='item in value'>{{item.value}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```